# Last ii value only return on second for loop

Tags: protractor

When I get `ii` value in `j` for loop it returns last value of `ii`, not incremented at first time.

Here is my code:

```
var tot_cnt = element.all(by.repeater("el in leaveApproved | orderBy:'Applied_Date' track by $index")).count().then(function(lev_req)
{
    if(lev_req > 0)
    {
        for (  var i=1; i <= lev_req ; i++)
        {
            var ii=i;
            //getting empl number
            var em = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='ibox_load']/table/tbody/tr["+ ii +"]/td[2]/div/div[2]/small[1]")).getText().then(function(emply_numb)
            {
                var em1 = element(by.xpath("//*[@id="ibox_load"]/table/tbody/tr["+ii+"]/td[2]/div/div[2]/span")).getText().then(function(leave_count)
                {
                    if(emply_numb == "188" && leave_count > 1)
                    {
                        for( var j=1; j <= leave_count; j++ )               
                        {
                            var jj=j;
                            console.log("ivalue"+ii); //here i get the last value of ii but i need the value from 1,2,3... like that
                            var st_dt_tmp = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='ibox_load']/table/tbody/tr["+ii+"]/td[3]/div["+jj+"]/div[1]/div[2]/strong[1]")).getText().then(function(st_tmp)
                            {
                                console.log("bf st dt "+st_tmp);
                            });
                    var ed_dt_tmp = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='ibox_load']/table/tbody/tr["+ii+"]/td[3]/div["+jj+"]/div[1]/div[2]/strong[2]")).getText().then(function(ed_tmp)
                    {
                        console.log("start "+ed_tmp+"and end date is"+end_date);
                    });
                                    
                }
                                                     
                    
            }
            });
        });
        }
    }
});
```

I need the ii value as 1,2,3 onwards when "ii" entered into j for loop

Comment: change all `var` to `let`

Comment: You overcomplecated your code in the first place. that's why i can't even figure out what you want to do, what actually happens and what the problem is. I would open another question where I specify what needs to be done in the first place. And I recommend you to start using `async/await` in your protractor code. it will make your code significantly clearer